# Stop Cron job for a particular time interval

Tags: cronjob

I have a cron job which runs every five minutes all day long.

I want to stop this cron job running on Sundays between 4pm and 5pm - it should start again after this time.

How can I script this?

Answer (score 4):

Stick this at the top of your cron job script (modified as you need)...

```
if [[ $(date +%u) -eq 7 && $(date +%H) -eq 16 ]]; then
  echo "I don't run at this time"
  exit 1
fi
echo "Something to do at other times here..."
```

The first instance of "date" returns the day of week (Sunday = 7), the second returns the hour (16 = 4.00pm - 4.59pm). If the script finds that it's currently day 7 and hour 16, it will exit.

Comment: You can further condense the check into a single date command if you want, if [ $( date +'%u:%H' ) = "7:16" ];

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
*/5 * * * * job.sh > /dev/null

00 16 * * 0 touch /tmp/stopJob.lck
00 17 * * 0 rm -f /tmp/stopJob.lck
```

In `job.sh` just quit if the file exists:

```
if [ -f /tmp/stopJob.lck ] 
then 
  exit
fi
```

Comment: There's just a slight risk that if the rm command isn't run for some reason (server restarted just before 1700, ntp time correction etc..), the main script will be skipped for a week. Likewise, if the touch is skipped, the main script will run when it shouldn't

Comment: Yes, that is true. For this Linker3000s approach is more stable. My solution is more self explaining by looking in the crontab.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need much if your cron job runs a script and you can make it check for the *absence* of a process set up to run between 4PM and 5PM on Sundays

For example, I use a cron job every 15 minutes which invokes `rsync` but *only if `rsync` is not already running*.

It uses the `pidof` command to check if a particular process id is running:

```
PID=$(pidof rsync)

if [ -z $PID ]
then 
    rsync -avz ....
fi
```

You will need to work out the details for your particular situation. I present it now as an idea to think about.